# Why is this getter throwing StackOverflowException, but only when called from one project?

Tags: .net, winforms, nunit, stack-overflow

I have a few projects:

- A database interface project that defines `Thingo` (main solution)
- A logic project that defines `ThingoChooser` (plugin solution)
- A GUI project that refers to the logic project (plugin solution
- A test project that refers to the logic project (plugin solution)

I'm debugging the plugin, so I run the main solution with its current working directory set to the `bin\Debug` directory targeted by all of the plugin projects. The main executable finds the plugin class in the GUI assembly and displays its main form.

In the test project, this code works fine:

```
this.chooser = new ThingoChooser();
foreach (var thingo in this.chooser.AvailableThingos) {
    Console.WriteLine(release);
}
```

The same code, posted into my GUI project, fails with a `StackOverFlowException` when `AvailableThingos` returns.

`ThingoChooser.AvailableThingos` looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Thingo> AvailableThingos {
        get {
            // Yes, it DEFINITELY case-matches the private variable,
            // NOT the public property. Oh, I wish this were that easy!
            return this.availableThingos;
        }

        private set {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

… and to what kind of `IEnumerable<Thingo>` do I set `this.availableThingos`?

It's a `List<Thingo>`.

Yes, I have a WinForms app that throws `StackOverFlowException` when trying to walk a `List<T>`. `:)`

VS2008 is perfectly happy to let me inspect `this.availableThingos` before it's returned. When I click the step button: `StackOverflowException`, every time. It also happens out of the debugger.

Fine waves of the dead chicken I've tried, most suggested by commenters, included:

- Looking at the stack trace for loops
- Changing the return type of `AvailableThingos` to `List<Thingo>`
- Removing `var` in case implicit typing stuffed me up
- Making the property's backing store variable `public` and hitting it directly
- Changing the backing store to a `List<T>`
- Removing LINQBridge and re-targeting to .NET 3.5

The changes don't help, and the stack trace doesn't show any loops. After one click of the “Step Into” button after the `}` of the getter, I get the exception warning float-over reading:

> **StackOverflowException was unhandled**
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The bug is at its most dramatic when I switch to .NET 3.5 *and* remove LINQBridge entirely *and* change the type of the backing store to `List<Thingo>` *and* access it directly *and* simply try this from the WinForms code:

```
List<Thingo> thingos = this.chooser.availableThingos.ToList();
```

Yep: calling `.ToList()` on a `List<Thingo>` can blow up with `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: what's the winform code look like? Are you certain the stack overflow isn't resulting from something you're doing with each list item in the form?

Comment: Can you make the field `availableThingos` public - and use `chooser.availableThingos` - just to remove the call of the property for debugging purposes?

Comment: from the post you've posted I'd say it's not the getter but the client code creating the SO and the getter just happens to be the last method on the stack so first question would be "What other methods are multiple times on the stack when you get the SO?" if you posted some of the stack trace that might help and/or the WinForm code

Comment: Yes, a stack trace would be welcome.

Comment: The WinForm code looks just like the code at the top: I pasted it in. 

The debugger's stack trace shows no repeats. I can't step my way to see a loop: I get StackOverflowException one "step" click after the closing curly brace in the getter.

Comment: I still get StackOverflowException when trying to enumerate the variable directly, bypassing the getter.

Comment: Is the target .net framework version same (for NUnit as well as winforms)?

Comment: Can you try writing the code without `var`? `foreach (Thingo release in this.chooser.AvailableThingos)`

Comment: Nice idea! It didn't work, though, I'm afraid. And now, it's after 1am and I better sleep. My kids will wake me up at 6am.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with Step Into (F11), even when you get to the end of your methods?  A stack trace with a breakpoint in the AvailableThingos property getter would be nice.  Side note, are you binding something to this list?

Comment: I'm stepping through with Step Into. Hit F11; see the return statement highlighted. Hit F11; see the closing curly brace of the getter highlighted. Hit F11; see the StackOverflowException.

Comment: I'm able to step past the problem by returning List<string> and setting my ComboBox' DataSource property to it directly. The GUI project's reference to the project with Thingo has copy-local set true. Perhaps what's happening is an endless conversion from Thingo to Thingo...

Comment: Yep. That's it. The StackOverflowException must be somewhere in the framework itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the **Copy Local settings** on the references.

The GUI project's reference to the database interface project had Copy Local set `True`. Its reference to the logic project had Copy Local set `False`. I suspect the logic project was returning an enumeration of a `Thingo` from a different DLL than the GUI project was seeing.

(Perhaps necessary for the problem to occur: when debugging, I'm running a fifth project which dynamically loads the DLL for the GUI project. That fifth project has its own copy of the database interface project DLL.)

The test project had Copy Local for both projects set `True`. Either the match helped, or just the fact that there was only one copy of the database interface DLL in the current working directory or on the path.

I'll happily accept the best answer describing *why* this caused `StackOverflowException`. I'd have strongly preferred a `DuplicateCopiesOfAssemblyYouDoofusException`.

For reference, here's the map of references and their Copy Local settings:

Main command project (run under debugger, dynamically loads GUI project from its `bin\Debug` directory):

- Has database interface DLL in same directory as the main executable. This is the same directory as all database interface references below target in their hint path.

GUI project (failing configuration):

- ref→ Database project: Copy Local = `True`
- ref→ Logic project: Copy Local = `False`

Logic project:

- ref→ Database project: Copy Local = `False`

Test project:

- ref→ Logic project: Copy Local = `True`
- ref→ Database project: Copy Local = `True`

In all fairness to the commenters, I didn't describe the solution layout in the question until five minutes ago, so I can't expect them to have solved it.